# Argument type __Event is not assignable to parameter type Event

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, type-definition

This is my JavaScript code:

```
class Dispatcher extends EventTarget {}

const dsp = new Dispatcher();
dsp.addEventListener('SOME_EVENT', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});

const evt = new Event('SOME_EVENT');
dsp.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

My IDE (PhpStorm) display this warning:

```
Argument type __Event is not assignable to parameter type Event
```

[image: IDE screenshot]

But the code runs perfectly:

```
/usr/bin/node /home/alex/.../main.js
Event {
  type: 'SOME_EVENT',
  defaultPrevented: false,
  cancelable: false,
  timeStamp: 33.53751400113106
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why the `Event` constructor returns the `__Event` object?

Comment: Maybe you ask this question at intellij-support, because, as you said, the return value of `new Event('evtType')` is an instance of `Event`. There is nothing like `__Event`. The Jetbrains guys might have an answer what the IDE actually is doing.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterSeliger. I've asked Jetbrains guys :)

Comment: Jetbrains guys said that this is my project configuration problem - the new empty project does not have this issue. So, we work with Jetbrains support to find the reason. Thanks to Jetbrains 'guy' Elena Pogorelova :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is delete the `./.idea/` folder from the root directory. The warning message will disappear.